# simple way to run code after solution deployment

Tags: deployment, events

Is there a simple way to run code after solution install and before solution uninstall ?
I know I can do that with feature but I don't want to use it.

Comment: Is there any good reason for you to not want to use EventReceivers, since this is the very purpose of the feature event receivers?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform additional tasks when a SharePoint project is deployed or retracted, you can handle events that are raised by Visual Studio.

For example:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.Deployment;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

namespace Contoso.ProjectDeploymentExtension
{
    [Export(typeof(ISharePointProjectExtension))]
    internal class ExampleProjectDeploymentExtension : ISharePointProjectExtension
    {
        public void Initialize(ISharePointProjectService projectService)
        {
            projectService.DeploymentStarted += ProjectService_DeploymentStarted;
            projectService.DeploymentCompleted += ProjectService_DeploymentCompleted;
        }

        void ProjectService_DeploymentStarted(object sender, DeploymentEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.DeploymentContext.IsDeploying)
            {
                string message = String.Format("Deployment started for the {0} project.",
                     e.Project.Name);
                e.DeploymentContext.Logger.WriteLine(message, LogCategory.Status);
            }
        }

        void ProjectService_DeploymentCompleted(object sender, DeploymentEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.DeploymentContext.IsDeploying)
            {
                string message = String.Format("Deployment completed for the {0} project.",
                     e.Project.Name);
                e.DeploymentContext.Logger.WriteLine(message, LogCategory.Status);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Reference**:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee843866.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially do it with a feature event reciever as described in [this article by microsoft.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231604.aspx)

> Feature event receivers are methods that execute when one of the
>   following feature-related events occurs in SharePoint:
>
> •A feature is installed.
>
> •A feature is activated.
>
> •A feature is deactivated.
>
> •A feature is removed.

Comment: The question states that he / she does not want to use EventReceivers for whatever reason!